map one column to other to fix nulls in a pyspark dataframe
I have a huge dataframe will multiple columns. Column brand has multiple nulls, and I want to fix them by using product_id as a map to fill as much nulls as possible. For example



brand
product_id




A
1234


B
5678


NULL
5678



And my expected result will be



brand
product_id




A
1234


B
5678


B
5678



To do this, first I create the mapping dataframe I want to use:
df= df[df["product_id"], df["brand"]].distinct()

Then I try to convert it to a dict, so I can use it in a mapping function:
dictionary = df_mapping.toPandas().set_index('product_id').to_dict()

But here I got a nested dictionary that I cannot use for the mapping
{'brand': {'18000928': 'samsung',
  '3200144': 'panasonic',
  '1004903': 'huawei',
  '5100575': 'apple',

Any solution to this? Is this the right approach?  I think there's no way to use replace using an entire dataframe as equivalence.
Thanks a lot!

Assuming it is a one to many relationship between brand and product id (i.e. 1 product_id can't have 2 brand), you can use a window function to achieve it without creating any reference:
df.withColumn(
    "brand_from_other_product",
    func.first("brand", ignorenulls=True).over(Window.partitionBy("product_id"))
).withColumn(
    "brand", func.coalesce("brand", "brand_from_other_product")
)

You can use a first function to get the first non null value in every partition.

wouldn't this need an orderBy?

@samkart based on the example that provided, I assume 1 product id should be matched to 1 brand only. Also, I have already ignored all the null value by using ignorenulls. Therefore, I believe orderBy is unnecessary.

what if the first value in the partition in null and second is non null? would it still work?

Yes, as setting ignorenulls to True will look for first non-null value. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.first.html
